# Book or story where people’s brains need computer assistance to function; crimes are punished by disconnecting said computer

Tags: story-identification, books

There is a book I saw once in the bookstore and have always regretted not reading. I maybe saw it in the early 2000s. 01-04?

The concept was that society is so advanced that everyone has a computer linked to their brains to help them process the overwhelming amount of information they encounter. Crimes are punished by disconnecting that computer and forcing people to live without the extra processing power. And the protagonist is maybe wrongfully convicted or involved in some kind of black market.

The central conflict is fuzzy but the concept is what stands out.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already but could you please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in?

Comment: Moxyland by Lauren Beukes? Criminals are punished by being disconnected, but it's mobile phones not brain implants that do the processing. Also this is 2008 so a few years later than you recall.

Comment: The concept seems similar to _Devil On My Back_ by Monica Hughes. (I don't claim this is the answer though.)

Comment: I’m pretty confident Psychohistorical Crisis is it! Thanks so much Lorendiac.  And thanks to all for your help - I may check out the others as well